# How to create an order/ranking for majors declared by each student

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has student ids and name of major along with semester. The main complicating factor, is that if a student returns to a previous major, I want it to count as another major

```
StudID   Major       Term
12345    History     202101
12345    History     202102
12345    Management  202201
12345    History     202202
```

Desired result

```
StudID   Major       Term    MajorNumber
12345    History     202101  1
12345    History     202102  1
12345    Management  202201  2
12345    History     202202  3
```

The only thing I have tried is pulling in the earliest term for each major then doing a ranking within StudentID based on each majors earliest term, but that means that final "history" becomes a 1 instead of 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `data.table::rleid` function does this. Specifically, it will give all consecutive values that are the same the same ID, and will increment whenever there is a change.

With data.table,

```
library(data.table)
your_dt = as.data.table(your_data)
your_dt[, MajorNumber := rleid(Major), by = .(StudID)]
your_dt
#    StudID      Major   Term MajorNumber
# 1:  12345    History 202101           1
# 2:  12345    History 202102           1
# 3:  12345 Management 202201           2
# 4:  12345    History 202202           3
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  group_by(StudID) %>%
  mutate(MajorNumber = data.table::rleid(Major)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I did add %>%arrange(StudID,Term) before group by

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`, use `ave` + `rle`

```
dat$MajorNumber <-  with(dat, as.integer(ave(Major, StudID, 
  FUN = \(x) with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))))
dat$MajorNumber
[1] 1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = cumsum(Major != lag(Major, default = Major[1]))+1)
```

```
  StudID      Major   Term x
1  12345    History 202101 1
2  12345    History 202102 1
3  12345 Management 202201 2
4  12345    History 202202 3
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best of the approach, but i tried the below code

### data

```r
data <- tribble(
~StudID,   ~Major,  ~Term,
12345,    'History',     202101,
12345,    'History' ,    202102,
12345,    'Management',  202201,
12345,    'History',     202202
)
```

### code

```r
data2 <- data %>% 
mutate(term2=substr(as.character(Term),1,4)) %>% 
group_by(StudID,Major,term2) %>%  slice(1) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
arrange(StudID,Term) %>% mutate(row=row_number())

data3 <- data %>% full_join(data2 %>% select(-term2), by=c('StudID','Term','Major')) %>% 
fill(row)
```

### output

[image]